# MacBook's Wi-Fi stopped working after upgrading to macOS Mojave and uninstalling Parallels

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

My 2017 MacBook Pro's Wi-Fi completely stopped working. It's an issue with the Mac because it used to connect to the Wi-Fi just fine, and my phone is still connected to it.

I upgraded from macOS High Sierra to macOS Mojave yesterday, but it still worked then. Today I un-installed Parallels, and immediately afterwards the Wi-Fi stopped working.

How do I reenable the Wi-Fi?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you go to System Preferences app → Network and see if Wi-Fi is listed in the sidebar on the left?

Comment: It is listed there, and various wifi networks are recognized. However they can't be joined to.

Comment: Click on the lock in the bottom left to unlock Network preference. Select the Wi-Fi item in the sidebar, and click on Advanced... button shown in bottom right. Now under Wi-Fi tab (first tab), select and delete the access point. Dismiss the sheet and re join the access point.

Comment: I removed the access point and when I try to connect again , this time prompted to fill a password, after I enter the password the connection still fails. I also tried to connect to my phone's hot spot but nothing works.

Comment: Next you can try by removing all Wi-Fi items from sidebar, and re-adding it clicking on the `+` button at the bottom. Also try restarting if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help either

Comment: There were some Wi-FI issues with macOS Mojave that were fixed in 10.14.4. What is your OS? Also https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202663

Comment: My operating system version is 10.14.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem actually stems from the usb c dongle.
[USB-C Dongles killing Wifi on 2016/2017 MacBooks – Who’s to blame?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329970/usb-c-dongles-killing-wifi-on-2016-2017-macbooks-who-s-to-blame)