# Problems with network connection after switching USB LAN hub (despite using wifi connection)

Tags: network, wifi, usb

I have a 2018 MBP running 10.14.x

I had it connected to a thunderbolt / USB-C to ethernet hub, [this model.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07FQD4KMV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) Which i was using as a USB hub and ethernet adaptor.

I recently moved desks and started using another thunderbolt / USB-C to ethernet hub the same model as the one above, but a different physical unit.

As soon as i did this the network connection to this machine was patchy, it kept dropping connection, even though the rest of the office was fine. Currently im working using wifi only, but the laptop keeps losing its IP. I can temporary fix the issue, but either renewing my DHCP lease, or turning off wifi and turning on wifi again. But this only lasts a while before the problem comes back. Any ideas ?

So far ive tried the following, but to no avail :

- Ive delete the USB LAN bridge from system preference > network.
- Run the computer using a wifi connection only
- Changed the location in system preferences > network, from "auto" to custom, to try and reset any network specific pre-sets.

Ive had this issue in the past when moving computers between desks and connecting them to new USBC ethernet adaptors, but in the past deleting the connection type in system preferences > network seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: So, go back and borrow the working hardware and see if it still works on your machine.  If it still works, replace faulty hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issues with some USB-C hubs and can mostly be blamed on shielding, some devices are worse, some better. There‘s less of an issue with 5GHz WiFi networks if that‘s an issue. Some people have also reported that wrapping metal foil around the USB-C cable works. But your best bet is probably switching your USB-C hub.

More information can be found in this thread: [USB-C Dongles killing Wifi on 2016/2017 MacBooks – Who’s to blame?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329970/usb-c-dongles-killing-wifi-on-2016-2017-macbooks-who-s-to-blame)