# USB Hub affects WiFi only once every few weeks

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, usb

[It is documented that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329970/197118) using certain USB C hubs. There even is an Apple support article that shows that this happens.

Now that's okay—I've come to accept that some dongles just don't cut it when coming to proper shielding. However, I have a hub and it exhibits some peculiar behavior. Most of the time it doesn't interfere with WiFi. However, it occasionally (once every one or two weeks) seems to cancel my WiFi signal. I know it's the hub's fault because when I unplug it, my WiFi starts working again. However, it starts working fine again after a while.

What could be a possible explanation of this?

Comment: @bmike’s answer in the linked question is the most accurate - physics.  Why only every couple weeks or so?  WiFi doesn’t use a single signal, it uses a range of frequencies in a band so it’s ver much possible that from time to time those frequencies “match.”  Get a USB extension cable to move your hub a sufficient distance from your WiFi antennas.  I’ve  done this numerous times with results that have yet to fail.

Comment: That's interesting. I suppose that'll be the best option then. Are you aware of any hubs which *don't* cause any WiFi interference?

Comment: On my personal iMac I use this [4-port aluminum wedge](https://amzn.to/3eu0xFB) and never once had interference. I also have two more powered Anker 7 port hubs but they have a 6 foot extension cable attached because i wanted a clean way to hide the connections under the desk.  Everyone  else (about a dozen or so people) who said they had WiF issues solved it with an extension usb.  One did it fir free with some aluminum foil, but hated the look

Comment: Oh, that's nice, thanks! I really wish there were some reputable USB C extension cables. All I find on amazon are ones from third parties that don't seem entirely reliable

Comment: " I really wish there were some reputable USB C extension cables. "  You won't find such a thing because USB-C extension cables would violate the published USB specification.  The only people willing to violate the spec like that are the kind of people with no reputation to lose.

Comment: @MacGuffin here is the page re: USB certification. https://compliance.usb.org/     Please indicate which part of the spec an extension cable would violate and how it would do so.

Comment: @Allan The document is here:  https://usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf  The section is 3.1 on page 37.  This lists all allowed cable assemblies and there is no mention of a USB-C plug to USB-C receptacle cable being allowed.  The how and why it violates the spec is complex but comes down to preventing people from stacking extension cables and wondering why nothing works.  There are inherent cable length limits and an extension cable will nearly certainly introduce too much resistance and delay for a reliable connection.

Comment: Nothing in those tables you’ve referenced mean what you think it means. Furthermore, the statement *The how and why it violates the spec is complex...* translates to you have no idea what you’re talking about.  So, allow me to put it into plain language - we’re talking about extending the cable from .5m to 1m in length, enough to get it away from the WiFi antenna, not to wrap it around the room.

Comment: The’s always a contrarian in the bunch, but it would be nice if you based you arguments on real world applications and not imaginary scenarios. If it were such a problem, it would be enumerated in the text and not left you your wild interpretation of it.

Comment: @Allan The question was why reputable manufacturers do not make USB-C extension cables.  I stated this is because it violates the spec, and I cited chapter and verse on where it violates the spec.  If you want to put your $1000+ computer at risk over a dodgy cable then be my guest.  I warned you and I'm not going to get into the details on why this is not part of the spec since space here does not allow for writing a thesis.  If you must know why it's not part of the spec then perhaps you should take that up with the people at the USB Implementers Forum.

Comment: You’re not going to get into details because you can’t.  I also don’t recall soliciting your “warnings” which somehow seemed to have morphed from inability to do so, to now damaging equipment.  Feel free to answer questions, but stay away from my postings as you simply bring too much negativity and misinformation.    I also notice you you didn’t  refute nor write your own answer on the linked question - that in and of itself speaks volumes.