# AOC Monitor and distorted audio with both Mac and Windows laptop

Tags: display, audio, usb

I bought a monitor from AOC (U27P2CA) and i have a problem with monitor's integrated speaker when i connect the monitor to the laptop with the usb-c port (with the hdmi cable everything works without any problem). When the monitor is connected via usb-c cable the speaker of the monitor emits a constant and disturbing hum that do not stop even when the speaker are in use. Anyone has some advice to solve the problem? The problem show up with mac and with window laptops.

Answer (score 0):

[USB-C cables and connectors may not have as much shielding for radio frequency interference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329971/5472) and may operate at power levels and cause higher interference.

It will be hard to guess where you’re getting interference, but trying cables you know are quality and seeing if you can isolate which item causes the most interference would be next steps if you don’t want to use the cable that your experiments already show aren’t as prone to your kit [amplifying and/or producing EFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) in your setup.

Comment: I am using the cable that was in the box of the monitor, but actually i tried to move the monitor downstairs (and I mean a floor below the surface) and removing all the possible interference sources (my watch, the dongles, smartphones...) but the noise persists... the next step is to convince the neighbourhoods to shut down all the electronic devices and see if it is that...

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying, but if you are not using the monitor speakers, just by setting the volume to 0 from the ">" button solves the issue.

Also connecting a speaker jack works, but I prefer the other solution.

Comment: Well actually I always use bluetooth headseat so I set volume to 0 and use them. But as you said it's annoying...