# iPhone causes latency issues when streaming on my Samsung TV

Tags: iphone, video, vpn, streaming

If I am watching a 2k or 4K movie stream with a Firestick on my Samsung TV, it immediately goes into a stutter/lag if my wife opens up YouTube, Facebook or Messenger on her iPhone 13 Pro.  Once she shuts it down, everything streams fine.  (I can't guarantee this, but I swear it will also hog the BW / latency on her iPad as well.)  If either, or both devices are idle. I don't see the lag.  Tried several players, playlists, VPN on & off, and VLC external video player.

Recently updated to Xfi 1.2G.  Worst case BW that I see was in the 50 MB's, but pings are in the 60 to 70 range. (ExpressVPN). This is with an Apple device causing the lag on the TV.  Best case w/o VPN may get to 200 Mbps, but pings are still above 50, and without an apple device signed in.

Is this due to Tizon, Firestick 4k or Apple OS?

thoughts?

Comment: Might this be a [case of USB-C or WiFi interference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329970/5472)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/) is always worth a look at for domestic wifi issues, though a VPN could also be suffering [QoS](https://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/) (Quality of Service) issues.

Comment: @bmike- this happens without being plugged in, so it's not dongle related.

Comment: @Tetsujin - QOS was my first thought.  Unfortunately, the new set ups that Xfinity sends you from Arris take all control of QOS, or IP management out of the Admin's hands and controls it on their end, somehow?